# Erro no JavaScript ao tentar remover elemento

Tags: javascript, html, aplicação-web

Fiz um método pra remover um item da minha tabela feita em *HTML* que é suprida por um formulário normal mas as informações vai pra tabela em questão... Até aí tudo normal, mas na hora de remover um item novo, sem ser o que já estava previamente cadastrado, não remove.

Aqui está meu projeto com o erro, hospedado pra vocês darem uma olhada no que estou falando: https://wesleyvicen1535.000webhostapp.com/CadastroPaciente.html

Até aí tudo tranquilo, o *script* remove tranquilamente os itens com a classe *"remover"*, mas os novos itens implementados não. Podem inspecionar elemento que vai mostrar que os novos estão indo com a classe.

Meu repositório no *Github* com o código fonte: https://github.com/wesleyvicen/ProjetoWebOdontologia

**Método remover:**

```
var removerTds = document.querySelectorAll('.remover');

removerTds.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
        var confirmacao = confirm('Deseja realmente remover este item?')
        if (confirmacao) {
            item.parentNode.remove();
        }
    })
});
```

**Implementa a tabela:**

```
var botao_cadastrar = document.querySelector("#btn_cadastrar");

 botao_atendimento.addEventListener("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        adicionar_atendimento();

    });

function adicionar_cadastro() {
    var nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value;
    var sobrenome = document.querySelector('#sobrenome').value;
    var cpf = document.querySelector('#cpf').value;
    var endereco = document.querySelector('#endereco').value;
    var numero = document.querySelector('#numero').value;
    var bairro = document.querySelector('#bairro').value;
    var cep = document.querySelector('#cep').value;
    var cep2 = document.querySelector('#cep2').value;
    var uf = document.querySelector('#uf').value;
    var cidade = document.querySelector('#cidade').value;
    var municipio = document.querySelector('#municipio').value;

    var tabela = document.querySelector(".tabelaCadastroCliente");

    var linha = document.createElement('tr');
    var td_nome = document.createElement('td');
    var td_sobrenome = document.createElement('td');
    var td_cpf = document.createElement('td');
    var td_endereco = document.createElement('td');
    var td_numero = document.createElement('td');
    var td_bairro = document.createElement('td');
    var td_cep = document.createElement('td');
    var td_uf = document.createElement('td');
    var td_cidade = document.createElement('td');
    var td_municipio = document.createElement('td');
    var td_remover = document.createElement('td');


    td_nome.textContent = nome +' '+ sobrenome;
    td_cpf.textContent = cpf;
    td_endereco.textContent = endereco;
    td_numero.textContent = numero;
    td_bairro.textContent = bairro;
    td_cep.textContent = cep +'-'+ cep2;
    td_uf.textContent = uf;
    td_cidade.textContent = cidade;
    td_municipio.textContent = municipio;
    td_remover.textContent = 'Remover';
    td_remover.classList.add('remover')

    linha.appendChild(td_nome);
    linha.appendChild(td_cpf);
    linha.appendChild(td_endereco);
    linha.appendChild(td_numero);
    linha.appendChild(td_bairro);
    linha.appendChild(td_cep);
    linha.appendChild(td_uf);
    linha.appendChild(td_cidade);
    linha.appendChild(td_municipio);
    linha.appendChild(td_remover);

    tabela.appendChild(linha);
};
```

Comment: **Wesley**, isso acontece porque o elemento não foi renderizado quando a página foi carregada, pelo contrário, você criou o mesmo depois de todo o processo, para resolver, você deve definir o evento dentro da função `adicionar_cadastro` veja: `td_remover.addEventListener('dblclick' ... `

Comment: eu entendi o que você falou, mas não entendi como posso resolver @NoobSaibot

Comment: Muito obrigado, resolveu meu problema, mas existe algum jeito de chamar novamente o método sem ser repetindo código?

Comment: Tem sim, você pode criar uma função e passar ela: `td_remover.addEventListener('dblclick', funcaoParaRemover);` , só tem que alterar `td_remover.parentNode.remove();` para `this.parentNode.remove();`

Comment: **Wesley** seja bem vindo, como um usuário novo, é importante saber como funciona o site, recomendo que leia o [tour] e caso necessite de ajuda em sobre como utilizar a ferramenta, acesse a [help].

Comment: [**Veja aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/9rw4xhyd/5/) o exemplo de como eu disse anteriormente.

Comment: Muito obrigado, me ajudou bastante

Answer (score 0):

```js
/**
*
* Use assim que funciona
*
*/
var removerTds = document.querySelectorAll('.remover');

for(i = 0; i < removerTds.length; i++)
{
 removerTds[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
  var confirmacao = confirm('Deseja realmente remover este item?')
  if(confirmacao){
   this.parentNode.remove();
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adicione o evento `dblclick` ao objeto `document` e verifique se o elemento clicado possui a classe `.remover`. Desta forma irá detectar o clique duplo também nos novos botões adicionados de forma dinâmica, e você não precisará fazer `forEach` para adicionar o evento a cada botão.

> Lembrando que a função `.remove()` não funciona no Internet Explorer.
>   Se isso for um inconveniente, troque por `.outerHTML = '';`.

Veja a abaixo o que foi removido e o que foi acrescentado no seu código original:

```
// CÓDIGO REMOVIDO

//var removerTds = document.querySelectorAll('.remover');

//removerTds.forEach(function (item) {
//    item.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
//        var confirmacao = confirm('Deseja realmente remover este item?')
//        if (confirmacao) {
//            item.parentNode.remove();
//        }
//    })
//});

// CÓDIGO ADICIONADO
document.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){

   if(e.target.className == 'remover'){
        var confirmacao = confirm('Deseja realmente remover este item?')
        if (confirmacao) {
            e.target.parentNode.remove();
        }
   }

});
```

> O `e.target` é o elemento clicado que disparou o evento, o
>   `.className` retorna a classe do elemento.

**Funcionamento:**

```js
// CÓDIGO REMOVIDO

//var removerTds = document.querySelectorAll('.remover');

//removerTds.forEach(function (item) {
//    item.addEventListener('dblclick', function () {
//        var confirmacao = confirm('Deseja realmente remover este item?')
//        if (confirmacao) {
//            item.parentNode.remove();
//        }
//    })
//});

// CÓDIGO ADICIONADO
document.addEventListener('dblclick', function(e){
   
   if(e.target.className == 'remover'){
        var confirmacao = confirm('Deseja realmente remover este item?')
        if (confirmacao) {
            e.target.parentNode.remove();
        }
   }
   
});
// FIM CÓDIGO ADICIONADO


var botao_atendimento = document.querySelector("#btn_atendimento");
var botao_cadastrar = document.querySelector("#btn_cadastrar");

//O IF agora vai selecionar qual dos botões foi clicado, se foi o do atendimento ou do cadastro.
if (botao_atendimento) { // criei este If e o proximo para não ficar sempre puxando o preventDefault()
    botao_atendimento.addEventListener("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault(); // Pega o evento e interrompe o evento normal
        adicionar_atendimento();

    });
} else if (botao_cadastrar) {
    botao_cadastrar.addEventListener("click", function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        adicionar_cadastro();

    });
}

//Metodo usado para o atendimento
function adicionar_atendimento() {
    var nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value; // Seleciona um elemento, neste caso o ID Nome
    var data = document.querySelector('#data').value;
    var descricao = document.querySelector('#descricao').value;

    var tabela = document.querySelector(".tabelaAtendimento");

    var linha = document.createElement('tr'); // Cria um elemento, neste Caso um tr
    var td_nome = document.createElement('td');
    var td_data = document.createElement('td');
    var td_descricao = document.createElement('td');

    td_nome.textContent = nome; // Retorna um nó do createElement, neste caso do td_nome
    td_data.textContent = data;
    td_descricao.textContent = descricao;

    linha.appendChild(td_nome); // Devolve uma referência ao nó adicionado, neste caso o td_nome
    linha.appendChild(td_data);
    linha.appendChild(td_descricao);

    tabela.appendChild(linha); // aqui retorna a referência ao nó adicionado no linha
};

function adicionar_cadastro() {
    var nome = document.querySelector('#nome').value;
    var sobrenome = document.querySelector('#sobrenome').value;
    var cpf = document.querySelector('#cpf').value;
    var endereco = document.querySelector('#endereco').value;
    var numero = document.querySelector('#numero').value;
    var bairro = document.querySelector('#bairro').value;
    var cep = document.querySelector('#cep').value;
    var cep2 = document.querySelector('#cep2').value;
    var uf = document.querySelector('#uf').value;
    var cidade = document.querySelector('#cidade').value;
    var municipio = document.querySelector('#municipio').value;

    var tabela = document.querySelector(".tabelaCadastroCliente");

    var linha = document.createElement('tr');
    var td_nome = document.createElement('td');
    var td_sobrenome = document.createElement('td');
    var td_cpf = document.createElement('td');
    var td_endereco = document.createElement('td');
    var td_numero = document.createElement('td');
    var td_bairro = document.createElement('td');
    var td_cep = document.createElement('td');
    var td_uf = document.createElement('td');
    var td_cidade = document.createElement('td');
    var td_municipio = document.createElement('td');
    var td_remover = document.createElement('td');


    td_nome.textContent = nome +' '+ sobrenome;
    td_cpf.textContent = cpf;
    td_endereco.textContent = endereco;
    td_numero.textContent = numero;
    td_bairro.textContent = bairro;
    td_cep.textContent = cep +'-'+ cep2;
    td_uf.textContent = uf;
    td_cidade.textContent = cidade;
    td_municipio.textContent = municipio;
    td_remover.textContent = 'Remover';
    td_remover.classList.add('remover')

    linha.appendChild(td_nome);
    linha.appendChild(td_cpf);
    linha.appendChild(td_endereco);
    linha.appendChild(td_numero);
    linha.appendChild(td_bairro);
    linha.appendChild(td_cep);
    linha.appendChild(td_uf);
    linha.appendChild(td_cidade);
    linha.appendChild(td_municipio);
    linha.appendChild(td_remover);

    tabela.appendChild(linha);
};
```

```css
/* RESET */

body {
    margin: 20px 0 0 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #f5f5f5
}

.corpo {
    width: 100%;
    height: 180px;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-right: -50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);

}

.tabela {
    border: 2px solid white;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

.centro {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

article {
    display: inline-grid;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

article:hover {
    border: 5px inset;
}

article span {
    color: ce2e3c;
    font-weight: 550;
}

/* Campos de formulário genéricos */


table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

th,
td {
    padding: 10px;
}

tr:nth-child(odd) {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #444
}

td:hover {
    background-color: #dedede;
}

tfoot td {
    background-color: #444;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bolder;
}

tfoot td:hover {
    background-color: #444;
}

textarea {
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px;
}

#cep {
    width: 6%;
}

#cep2 {
    width: 5%;
}

.btn {
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 330px;
    height: 45px;
    margin: 0.5em;
    background-color: #f48888;
    color: white;
    font-weight: 600;
}

#acao {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
}

.remover {
    background-color: darkred;
    color: white;
    cursor: hand;
}

.remover:hover {
    background-color: red;

}

.btn:hover {
    background-color: #f26464
}

textarea,
input[type="text"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="number"] {
    border: 2px #cccccc solid;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 0 20px;
}


input[type="text"],
input[type="datetime-local"],
button[type="submit"],
input[type="search"],
input[type="number"] {
    height: 32px;
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 14px;
}

textarea:hover,
input[type="text"]:hover,
input[type="datetime-local"]:hover,
input[type="search"]:hover,
input[type="number"]:hover {
    background-color: #ddddff;
}

textarea:focus,
input[type="text"]:focus,
input[type="datetime-local"]:focus,
input[type="search"]:focus,
input[type="number"]:focus {
    background: #ffcccc;
}
```

```html
    <main class="centro">
        <form class="form">
            <input id="nome" type="text" placeholder="Nome" name="nome" autofocus>
            <input id="sobrenome" type="text" placeholder="Sobrenome" name="sobrenome"><br>
            <input id="cpf" type="number" placeholder="CPF" name="cpf" maxlength="11"><br>
            <input id="endereco" type="text" placeholder="Endereço" name="endereco">
            <input id="numero" type="number" placeholder="Número" name="numero"><br>
            <input id="bairro" type="text" placeholder="Bairro" name="bairro"><br>
            <input id="cep" type="text" name="cep" size="3" maxlength="5" placeholder="CEP"> - <input id="cep2" placeholder="CEP" type="text" name="cep2" size="3" maxlength="3"><br>
            <input id="uf" type="text" placeholder="UF" name="uf" maxlength="2"><br>
            <input id="cidade" type="text" placeholder="Cidade" name="cidade"><br>
            <input id="municipio" type="text" placeholder="Distrito" name="municipio"><br>
            <button id="btn_cadastrar" class="btn" type="submit" style="cursor:hand" name="cadastrar">Cadastrar</button>
        </form>

        <table class="tabela tabelaCadastroCliente">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Nome</th>
                    <th>CPF</th>
                    <th>Endereço</th>
                    <th>Número</th>
                    <th>Bairro</th>
                    <th>CEP</th>
                    <th>UF</th>
                    <th>Cidade</th>
                    <th>Distrito</th>
                    <th id="acao">Ação</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <td>Wesley Vicente</td>
            <td>11951606400</td>
            <td>Praça Joaquim Nabuco</td>
            <td>10</td>
            <td>Centro</td>
            <td>55850-000</td>
            <td>PE</td>
            <td>Vicência</td>
            <td>Vicência1</td>
            <td class="remover">Remover</td>
            <tfoot>

                <td colspan="10">Isso é tudo</td>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </main>
```

Comment: Muito bom cara, resolveu complementarmente o que eu estava procurando e ficou mais enxuto o código.

Comment: Que bom. Vc deve escolher a melhor resposta que achou e marcar ✔️.